# Custom shipping calculation returns wrong price only while editing order in backend

Tags: magento-1, shipping, sales

I build a custom module for shipping that has several price options. It works well in frontend.

But when we need to edit an order already placed in admin, I can't get the custom prices. It always shows the default price only.

How to overcome this situation? I searched for a while but does not get any solution.

Comment: Could you shortly describe, what you did so far?

Comment: Without specific details on how your module is built, the only possible answers are blind guesses as to why it is not working properly.

Comment: The flow in admin is very similar to frontend, there are just a couple of subtle differences that you are unlikely to hit. Debugger is your friend here.

Comment: Closing this for now - please edit to provide some additional details on your custom module.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there might be some necessary information missing when placing a new order in the backend (because editing an existing order means canceling the old one and creating a copy).

Have a look on your price calculation routine and closely observer which information it depends on.

Maybe your are depending on data of the checkout controller? That would be a bad idea, because there is no checkout controller involved in the backend.